# React redux First object missing on rendering when data is entered in the text field

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

What am I trying to do : Trying to enter the first name and last name of a person and display all the entered name below using redux global state management.

When I try to create a new object by entering data into the input fields, the 1st item is being displayed empty both on the view page and console log and from the 2nd item, all the items are being displayed correctly. I encountered this error previously but couldn't fix it.

Actual page:

```
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {useState}  from 'react';

const Inc = ()=>{
    const[data, setData] = useState({});
    const[firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const[lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
    const newData={
        first_name: "",
        last_name : ""

    }
    const handleFieldFirst=async (e)=>{
        await setFirstName(e.target.value);

    }
    const handleFieldLast= async (e)=>{
        await setLastName(e.target.value);

        
    }
    const handler = async (e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        newData.first_name = firstName ;
        newData.last_name = lastName ;
        await setData(newData);
        console.log(data);
        dispatch({type: 'INC', payload : data});
        document.getElementById("form1").reset();

    }

    return(
        <form id="form1" type ="submit" name="login" >
            <input onChange={e => handleFieldFirst(e)} name="first" type="text" placeholder="First name"></input>
            <input onChange={e => handleFieldLast(e)} name="last" type="text" placeholder="Last name"></input>
            <button onClick={e => handler(e)}>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Inc;
```

View page

```
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
const Disp = ()=>{
    const count = useSelector(state => state.counterReducer);
    return(
      <div>
         {count.map((d) => <li key={d.last_name}>{d.first_name} {d.last_name}</li>)}
      </div>
    );
}

export default Disp;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh14z.png)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to change your code. you have to use `async` and `await` only if the function returns a promise

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const Inc = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: "INC", payload: data });
    setData({
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
    });
  };

  return (
    <form id="form1" type="submit" name="login">
      <input
        onChange={(e) =>
          setData({
            ...data,
            firstName: e.target.value,
          })
        }
        name="first"
        type="text"
        placeholder="First name"
        value={data.firstName}
      />
      <input
        onChange={(e) =>
          setData({
            ...data,
            lastName: e.target.value,
          })
        }
        name="last"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Last name"
        value={data.lastName}
      />
      <button onClick={handler}>Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Inc;
```

by default `useSelector` will return the default state (you didn't attach reducer code so I'm assuming that the reducer returns default state) so add a condition to render `<li>....</li>` only the length of the array is greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot this clarified my doubt. I have one question - when we enter first name or last name that data is being loaded into data state via set data, since both first name and last name are the members of same object. But since we are pushing the first name and last name separately i.e. via onchange on 2 different input boxes how does react know that the entered first name and last name belong to same object?